# I want to play video if screen off in exoplayer android, how?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

Exoplayer stop video when screen off,
I need to playing video when screen off. Is this possible in android exoplayer?

Comment: use helper in that and onpause call exoPlayerHelper.play();

Comment: check in activity.... when state is onPause() remove the code it will be look like exoplayer.pause()

Comment: Do you want to avoid screen going off or do you want to continue playing (audio) when the screen is off?

Comment: @raxerz playing audio when screen off

Comment: @PrashantAGosai you can't see the video while the screen is off, right?